# How to post to a fan page from an application as the brand?

Tags: c#, .net, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I want to post a message to a fan page from an application as the brand using the Facebook SDK.

I tried using the following token and code to post to a fan page, but I get a `bad request` error:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/me/accounts?access_token=XXXXXXXX
```

With output similar to the following:

```
{
   "data": [
      {
         "name": "My App",
         "category": "Application",
         "id": "10258853",
     "access_token": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
      }
   ]
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, actually my sollution seemed to be just fine :)
Here's how to do it:
1. Make sure you are administrator of the facebook page on wich you want to post.
2. Get your access_token here:

```
https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?
   client_id=[APP ID]
&response_type=token
&scope=publish_stream,manage_pages, offline_access
&redirect_uri=[The page you want to be redirected after you get you token, must be the same domain as your application]
```

3. Get your access_token for a specific page/application here:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/me/accounts?access_token=[ACCESS_TOKEN FROM STEP 2]
```

You'll see something like this:

```
{
     "name": "Your Page",
     "category": "Community",
     "id": "145530142139075",
     "access_token": "yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy"
  },
```

4. You can now start posting to your page.

```
    https://graph.facebook.com/[YOUR PAGE ID FROM STEP 3]/feed
access_token=[ACCESS_TOKEN FROM STEP 3]
```

I hope this will help others.

Answer (score 2):

The data you are receiving seems to be your own account details.

To be able to post to a feed your app needs to:

- Be authenticated
- Have the publish_stream permission from the owner of the feed
- Use this url: https://graph.facebook.com/CLIENT_ID/feed?access_token=XXXXXX where CLIENT_ID is the id of the feed-owner.
- set message to be posted as a post variable named message in the request
- be sent as a POST

hope these points help you out.

Comment: I think this will help me a lot! Where is the documentation for this kind of information? I'll try it immediatly and mark your answer if it works. thx man!

Comment: Ok, no. what access_token do i need? i want to post as the administrator of the fan page. Can i use my access_token? I have publish_stream permission. Ad Client_id, i use the id of the fanpage.

Comment: this is where I found the info http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/post/. I think your right to use the id of your fanpage as the CLIENT_ID, but I am not really sure about which accesstoken to use.

Comment: Ok, i think there were some other problems in my code. Because now it works just fine. I've posted a sollution for other users in the future. Thanks for your responses.